# Strange result when using recurrence to compute time-complexity of evaluating polynomial at n points without fft

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to understand the fft's benefit to time-complexity by deriving the runtime of polynomial evaluation that doesn't share computation, but running into some weirdness. (I know the answer is O(n^2), but I just wanted to set things up in a similar recursive context to the fft).

So if we're just evaluating an nth order polynomial recursively (by splitting it up into even and odd sub-polynomials recursively, then constant-time adding the result), the recurrence should be T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + O(1), which has runtime O(n).

But then if I do this naively for n points (without any special fft sharing magic), the recurrence I get is $T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + O(n)$, since every node has to do n additions, but this has time-complexity O(n*log(n)), which seems wrong, since I just did an O(n) thing n times.

The recurrence solving theorem I'm using is from the Dasgupta algorithms book:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but $T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + O(n)$ would be correct only if you just evaluated a double-degree polynomial for the same number of points. As soon as the number of points is doubled, too, it will be $T(n) = 4*T(n/2) + O(n)$, and that's $O(n^2)$, as was to be expected.